# When reviewing reopen queue, can we have the major revisions to compare against?

Tags: feature-request

When looking at the side-by-side diff view, I don't see the most significant revisions.  For example, if the last edit was a minor grammar change, I will see the minor grammar change.  I want to see for example if the user has added code to demonstrate effort or attempts to reduce misunderstanding or explain why this is not a duplicate.

Can we have a merge of all revisions since the question was closed?  Or perhaps only edits made by the OP and disregard other editors during that period of time.

Comment: I wouldn't want to see *only* code edits, because non-code edits can be *very* relevant, but seeing the diff between when it was closed and now seems useful.

Comment: Why only the revisions since it was closed? Considering there's always an inescapable pile-on-effect, sometimes questions still get closed long after all criticisms leading the first person to close-vote have been dealt with commendably. So, showing a merger of all revisions since the first close-vote was logged might be even better...

Comment: @Deduplicator If you want to see everything you can always go and look at the full revision history of the post.  The idea proposed here is not to show all revisions, but a *merge* of all revisions.  in effect the diff between the revision when the post was closed and the current revision, so just *one* diff would be shown.  If more information was needed, it would be worth the extra two clicks to just go inspect the full revision history.

Comment: @Servy: I understood that, I just suggested that the revision the *first* vote was cast on might be even more appropriate for comparison, than the one the *last* voter saw.